# How to make one window resizable and one window not resizable?

Tags: python, kivy

I and my friends are making an app in Kivy, and we want to have the login screen window be non-resizable, but we also want the main screen to be resizable. We were unable to find a solution online, so we we wondering if anyone knows how to achieve this. Here is our code for reference:

Python Code

```
from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1500')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1000')
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_width', '1500')
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_height', '1000')
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')

import kivy
kivy.require('2.2.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.animation import Animation

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class KeepUp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.fullscreen = 0
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KeepUp().run()
```

Kivy file

```
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#: import StringProperty kivy.properties.StringProperty
#: import OptionProperty kivy.properties.OptionProperty
#: import NumericProperty kivy.properties.NumericProperty

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WindowManager:
    LoginScreen:
    HomeScreen:
    SettingsScreen:

<MyPopup@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Are you sure?"
    title_size: 20
    title_font: 'Gabriola.ttf'
    size_hint: .3, .2
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text: 'Your name cannot be changed once it is set.'
            font_size: 30
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4}
        Button:
            text: 'Yes!'
            font_size: 24
            size: 424.5, 60
            on_release:
                root.dismiss()
                app.root.current = "Home"

<Label>
    markup: True
    font_name: 'Gabriola.ttf'
    size_hint: None, None

<LoginScreen>
    name: "Login"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 187/255.0, 255/255.0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height

        Image:
            source:'logo.png'
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.005, "top": 0.99}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 75, 75
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False

        Label:
            id: Title
            text:'[b]Welcome to KeepUp![/b]'
            font_size: 210
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7}
        
        Label:
            id: nameq
            text:"[b]What's your name?[/b]"
            font_size: 100
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.45}
        
        TextInput:
            id: namea
            multiline: False
            size_hint: .3, .05
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3}
        
        Button:
            text: 'Submit'
            font_size: 48
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.15}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.1
            on_release: Factory.MyPopup().open()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<HomeScreen>
    name: "Home"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 187/255.0, 255/255.0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height

        Image:
            source:'logo.png'
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.005, "top": 0.99}
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 75, 75
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Label:
            id: Title
            text:'[b]Welcome, Name![/b]'
            font_size: 65
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.21, "top": 0.996}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<SettingsScreen>
    name: "Settings"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you all for your help!